# When do iTunes Connect Stats update?

Tags: app-store-connect, ratings

I've read in quite a few places that sales trend reports update anywhere between 3AM - 5AM Cupertino time once a day.

**But what about other stats?**

1. When do app ratings update?
2. When do customer reviews update?

Comment: btw, it's not official but there is a twitter account, @itcstatus, you can follow which tweets within 15 minutes of the trend reports being updated.

Comment: @Jonathan. Hmm, okay, I'll check that out too. But I am more interested in when the ratings and reviews update. I would imagine they update more frequently, but I can't find that info anywhere.

Comment: Sorry i don't know the other parts, which is why i posted a comment not answer, sorry if I got your hopes up :)

Comment: No, actually, that twitter account had a service, which I like, so although it doesn't answer my question, it's a good comment, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Both of those usually update almost instantly. Sometimes it may take a few minutes, but I've experienced instant results from people posting ratings and reviews.
Thanks!